# excel check whether a combination of cells in a row exists in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked around and I can't find it.

So lets say I have an array of these unique strings:

```
Dim uniques(10) As String
```

Now each of these Strings are represented in the A column on the spreadsheet.

Also I have a range of Integers going from 1 - 365 representing unique values in column B. The ith day i

My conundrum is:
I want to know whether there exists a row where A is uniques(1) and b is i
and I want to itterate this process through all uniques and all possible i's

I'm looking for an efficient way to do this, anything better than looping through the range in question, for each unique, for each day.
For the record my actual data is counting every day of the year and the number of days since a certain event has happened so my number of rows can grow as large as 365^2 and maybe even more if the event happened more than a year ago.

COUNTIFS seems to work pretty good. I wish I I could just go:

```
numOfOccurences = Sheet1.Countifs(countrange,dayrange,uniques(1),irange,i)
```

And if numOfOccurences is greater than 0 then I know it exists.

Or is there a function that breaks a Range into rows in a vba array?
So that it looks like this {[A2,B2],[A3,B3],...} I could do some damage with that because both the columns come sorted, A then B. I'm just not looking forward to making the function myself.

All ideas are appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "the ith day i"? Do you mean that e.g. B100 contains the number 100?

Comment: no B100 can be anything. i is just the number in the in the range 0-365, or more if its been more than a year since the event occured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works. It might not be optimal but shows how to iterate through the rows in a range:

```
Sub test()
    Dim count As Long, i As Long
    Dim myRow As Range
    Dim uniques As Variant
    uniques = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i") 'for example
    i = 12 'for example
    For Each myRow In Range("A1:B365").Rows
        If myRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = uniques(1) And myRow.Cells(1, 2).Value = i Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next myRow
    MsgBoxS count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you, or at least get you started in the right direction.  It finds all occurrences of the 10 unique values and then gets the corresponding numbers for them from column B.  I don't know how you're populating your unique values, so I just made something up.  The Range.Find loop should be relevant to you largely unchanged.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim arrUnq(1 To 10) As String
    Dim varUnq As Variant
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strResults As String

    arrUnq(1) = "aaa"
    arrUnq(2) = "bbb"
    arrUnq(3) = "ccc"
    arrUnq(4) = "ddd"
    arrUnq(5) = "eee"
    arrUnq(6) = "fff"
    arrUnq(7) = "ggg"
    arrUnq(8) = "hhh"
    arrUnq(9) = "iii"
    arrUnq(10) = "jjj"

    For Each varUnq In arrUnq
        Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find(varUnq, Cells(Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            Do
                'Here you can check what value is in column B by using rngFound.Offset(, 1).Value
                'You can use this to compare to something you're looking for, or just record the result as shown in this code

                strResults = strResults & Chr(10) & varUnq & ": " & rngFound.Offset(, 1).Value

                'Advance to the next found instance of the unique string
                Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find(varUnq, rngFound, xlValues, xlPart)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        End If
    Next varUnq

    If Len(strResults) > 0 Then
        strResults = Mid(strResults, 2) 'Get rid of opening chr(10)
        MsgBox strResults
    Else
        MsgBox "No matches found for any of the 10 unique values"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: can I see you ammend your answer to make a map of maps of results so that dict["ggg"][7] would equal true or something like that?  Forgive the syntax, I'm new to vb and never used its maps before.